# How to set localization in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

How can I set localization in asp.net?

I need to display in Arabic instead of English.
Asp.net in multilingual so using localisation I did.But adding .resx not getting result.

Anybody tell me Step by step procedure.

Comment: I would take a look at the following question with answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275016/the-correct-way-of-using-multilingual-support

Answer (score 0):

This page can show you step by step ,

[Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) !

Answer (score -1):

"Solution Explorer"
right-click the root of your Web site
Add "ASP.NET Folder"
click "App_GlobalResources"
Right-click the "App_GlobalResources folder"
"Add New Item"
In the list, click "Resource File"
In the Name box, type "LocalizedText.resx"
click "Add"
The "LocalizedText.resx" file (acts as the resource for the fallback culture)
Create a second .resx file
name it "LocalizedText.fr.resx"(The string "fr" identifies the file as the resource to use if the browser's language is set to French)
Create a third .resx file
name it "LocalizedText.es-mx.resx"(The string "es-mx" identifies the file as file as the resource to use if the browser's language is set to Spanish (Mexico))
Open the "LocalizedText.resx" file.
In the first row under the Name column type "Msg1".
In the first row under the Value column, type "Hello"
Save the file and close it --> Open the "LocalizedText.fr.resx"
create a resource string named "Msg1" --> assign it the value "Bon jour"
Now 1st file is done --> save and close the file
Open the "LocalizedText.es-mx.resx"
create a resource string named "Msg1"
assign it the value "Buenos días".
Now 2nd file is done
save and close the file.